# Show: $\|u_n\|_X \leq \gamma^{n-1} \|u_0\|_X \quad \forall n \geq 1$

Tags: numerical-methods, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, direct-sum

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with norm $\|\cdot\|_X$ and scalar product $(\cdot,\cdot)_X$ , which is the direct sum of the subspaces $V$ and $W$. Regarding $V$ and $W$ it holds the intensified Cauchy Schwarz Inequality.

> > What do I mean with intensified Cauchy Schwarz Inequality? : There is a $\gamma$ with $0 \leq \gamma < 1$ and $|(v,w)|_X \leq \gamma \|v\|_X \|w\|_X \quad \forall v \in V, w \in W$

$P_V$ and $P_W$ are the orthogonal projections on $V$ and $W$. For a $u_0 \in X$ we compute $u_{2k-1} = P_V u_{2k-2}$ and $u_{2k} = P_W u_{2k-1}$.

Show: $\|u_n\|_X \leq \gamma^{n-1} \|u_0\|_X \quad \forall n \geq 1$

My thoughts: It is clear that we have use the Cauchy Schwarz inequality. I mean there is our $\gamma$. It seems that we have use the inequality multiple times to get $\gamma^{n-1}$.We also have to use the successive computation somehow. Maybe my idea is too simple but can induction help us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: We have $\lVert P_Wv\rVert^2=(v,P_Wv)_X$ and $\lVert P_Vw\rVert^2=(P_Vw,w)_X$.

Comment: Thanks for your hint! We tried to solve this exercise with induction, but we still have a problem. Here is our solution: induction basis: For $$n=1$$ we have (because of the recursion, the Cauchy-Schwarz-inequality,  $||P_Vu_0||_X\le||u_0||_X$, $\gamma\in[0,1]$ and your hint): $$||u_1||_X^2=||P_Vu_0||_X^2=<u_0,P_Vu_0>_X\le\gamma||u_0||_X||P_Vu_0||_X\le||u_0||_X^2\Leftrightarrow||u_1||_X\le||u_0||_X$$.

Comment: For the induction step $n\rightarrow n+1$ we need a case differentiation. Case $n+1$ is even (case $n+1$ is odd is analogue): $$||u_{n+1}||_X^2=||P_Wu_n||_X^2=<u_n,P_Wu_n>_X\le\gamma||u_n||_X||P_Wu_n||_X\le\gamma||u_n||_X^2$$ Now we use the induction hypothesis and get: $$\le\gamma(\gamma^{n-1}||u_0||_X)^2=\gamma^{2n-1}||u_0||_X^2$$ And here is the problem. We need for the proof to show: $||u_{n+1}||_X^2\le\gamma^{2n}||u_0||_X^2$. Then we can take the root again. We don't know how we get the missing $\gamma$.

Comment: You should first use $\lVert P_Vw\rVert^2=\langle P_Vw,w\rangle_X\leq\gamma\lVert P_Vw\rVert\cdot\lVert w\rVert$ to derive $\lVert P_Vw\rVert\leq\gamma\lVert w\rVert$, then induction step is clear.

Comment: Thank you very much! We got it.